# Getting Link errors when crypto++ lib used in my MFC application

Tags: encryption, mfc, aes, linker-errors, crypto++

I am trying to encrypt some files using crypto++. I have found a useful article.
http://programmingknowledgeblog.blogspot.com/2013/04/compiling-and-integrating-crypto-into.html

I have created a sample project as in the tutorial. It works fine. Then I have tried to use the same in my MFC application. I have linked the cryptlib.lib correctly in project properties. But I am getting lot of LINK errors.

[image]

I have tried by changing the **Runtime Library** to **Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)** and **Use of MFC** as **Use MFC in a Shared DLL**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also see [Visual Studio | Runtime Linking](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Visual_Studio#Runtime_Linking) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: As per the article I have used the below command to build the solution **msbuild "C:\Users\prasanth.sivan\Desktop\Crypto++\cryptest.sln" /target:build "/property:Configuration=Debug;RuntimeLibrary=3"**. But I am getting the link errors again.